# WYSIWYG editor and innerHTML in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement a WYSIWYG editor and show on HTML your content, but I have two main problems... Let's to code...

**"Register/Upload component .ts"** (I'm using [AngularEditor](https://github.com/kolkov/angular-editor))

```
editorConfig: AngularEditorConfig = {
        editable: true,
        spellcheck: true,
        height: 'auto',
        minHeight: '300px',
        maxHeight: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        enableToolbar: true,
        showToolbar: true,
        placeholder: 'Enter text here...',
        sanitize: true,
        toolbarPosition: 'top',
        toolbarHiddenButtons: [
            ['strikeThrough', 'superscript', 'subscript'],
            ['heading', 'fontName', 'fontSize', 'color'],
            ['justifyFull', 'indent', 'outdent'],
            ['cut', 'copy', 'delete', 'removeFormat', 'undo', 'redo'],
            ['paragraph', 'removeBlockquote'],
            ['textColor', 'backgroundColor'],
            ['insertImage', 'insertVideo'],
            ['link', 'unlink', 'image', 'video'],
            ['toggleEditorMode'],
        ],
    };
```

**"Register/Upload component .html"**

```
<angular-editor
  formControlName="description"
  [config]="editorConfig"
></angular-editor>
```

**QUESTION 1:** Everything here works fine. But when I go to update the value, show a raw HTML inside the editor and not the formated text... How I can fix this?

I another problem, the innerHTML doesn't work with the data came from the database.

```
<div class="breaklines" [innerHTML]="prop.description | safeHtml"></div> <--- NOT WORK
<div class="breaklines" [innerHTML]="'<strong>text directly</strong>'"></div> <--- WORK, even the same content
```

I created the pipe to safe html:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml', pure: false })
export class SafeHtml implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform(content) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
    }
}
```

**QUESTION 2:** Do I need handler my HTML save on database, before try bind it?

Thanks everybody!

**UPDATE**
I'm discovery why innerHTML doesn't work with the saved code. When I make get the code comes < instead of < in all HTML tags. Then I make a simple replace and everything work

```
this.desc = prop.description.replace(/&lt;/g, '<');
<div class="breaklines" [innerHTML]="desc | safeHtml"></div>
```

Now, I only need to know how I can format the html in the editor when I going to update an information... Thanks!

Comment: prop it's your formGroup?

Comment: Yes, it's actually my subscribe in service to get items in back-end.

Comment: ok, but when backend returns, you should patch on form, that will update on editor and HTML "preview". Are you doing this?

Comment: Yes, I do a patchValue on the form

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that saving your html in a database would change anything. It seems like you are currently sanitizing your input twice :

- once in `SafeHtml`
- once in your editor config `sanitize: true,`

You might try to set sanitize to false in the editor config ?

Comment: The problem is that the string in database come with &lt; instead of <, I make a replace and all works